# Why did I get an incubator from a Pokéstop?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was driving home and stopped by a Pokéstop to stock up on balls and potions, but I was surprised to get an Incubator among my loot. Are these now in the Pokéstop reward pool?

[image: incubator from Pokéstop]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is part of the Christmas event, described [here](http://pokemongolive.com/en/post/holiday2016/):

> Starting the morning of December 25, 2016, and through the afternoon of January 3, 2017 (PST), PokéStops will award one single-use Incubator each day after your first Photo Disc spin.

Thus, you'll be able to get one Incubator a day for a full 10 days during this event, which will allow you to hatch a single egg each!

Comment: Well, that's gonna make some cleaning in those eggs. Another motivation to go out in the cold.

Comment: @Isuka too bad it's 80 here